# Simple Error Message no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, qt

Whenever I compile my program I  get an error message of:

```
no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::sort(QStringList&, int&)'
     sort(listt,x);
```

I also declared the sort function as public in my header. This is probably a very simple error and forgive me for that i'm really new at C++. However any input on what I did wrong would be greatly appreciated:

```
// mainwindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include <sstream>

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    QStringList sort(QStringList a);

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H


// mainwindow.cpp
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include "ui_mainwindow.h"
    #include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
    #include <QtCore>
    #include <QFile>
    #include <QDebug>
    #include <sstream>

    using namespace std;

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ...
    }

    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {
        ...
    }

    QStringList sort(QStringList a, int n)
    {
        ...
    }

    void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
    {
        ...
        sort(listt,x)
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `MainWindow::` in your function definition.

```
QStringList sort(const QStringList & a, int n) {         
    ...
}
```

should be:

```
QStringList MainWindow::sort(const QStringList & a, int n) {
    //Your code
}
```

Also the prototype should probably be (in the header file):

```
QStringList sort(const QStringList & a, int n);
```

Seeing as you get the error for making a call to the version defined in the .cpp file.

Complex types for in-arguments should usually be passed by const reference.

Comment: That gave an error of "prototype for ... does not match any in class 'MainWindow'

Comment: Because int n is not defined as a parameter in the header file. Remove it from the declaration or add it in the header.